# Display interface + ip list nice way

Tags: bash

I have to display net interface and IP's attached to it.

I came up with this code:

```
if [ -f intf ]; then
  rm -I intf
fi &&
if [ -f ipl ]; then
  rm -I ipl
fi &&
ip ntable | grep dev | sort | uniq | sed -e 's/^.*dev //;/^lo/d' >> intf &&
ip a | grep -oP "inet\s+\K[\w./]+" | grep -v 127 >> ipl &&
paste <(cat intf) <(cat ipl)
```

It does the job but I believe it's ugly :), created files, IMHO a total mess :)
any one can suggest the nice way to get exact the same result but short and efficient way ?

If there are a few interfaces, right now I'm thinking about looping, but that will make this code even bigger and probably uglier :)  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

As the first thing, you can eliminate the need for temporary files with process substitution:

```
paste <(ip ntable | grep dev | sort -u | sed -e 's/^.*dev //;/^lo/d') <(ip a | grep -oP "inet\s+\K[\w./]+" | grep -v 127)
```

- `sort -u` does the same thing as `sort | uniq`

Comment: Thanks @codeforester  This way it looks much better :  paste <(ip ntable | grep -oP "dev\s+\K[\w./]+"| grep -v lo | sort -u) <(ip a | grep -oP "inet\s+\K[\w./]+" | grep -v 127)      ,  can u advice in case of few interfaces,   can I avoid looping ?

Answer (score 0):

This oneliner outputs the interface name and its ip address:

```
ifconfig |\
grep -e 'Link' -A 1 |\
paste -d" " - - - |\
grep ' addr' |\
sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/Link.*addr://' |\
cut -d" " -f1,2
```

Here an explanation of the commands:

1. Shows network configuration
2. Filters lines containing *Link* and the next line to it.
3. Joins three lines
4. Filters lines having an assigned address
5. Trim whitespaces and remove not relevant information
6. Splits remaining data and keeps only interface name and ip address.

Example output:

```
br-2065e5d2fc59 172.18.0.1
docker0 172.17.0.1
lo 127.0.0.1
wlp3s0
```